# Joomla not being able to see your content

Tags: html, joomla, joomla3.0

I am new to joomla. I recently downloaded a joomla template and I am trying to edit that into a my own design. When I try to add a new page I do this:

1. Article Manager: Add New Article
2. Menu Manager: Edit Menu Item
3. link article to the menu item
4. for template style I use the template default.

the new page is about us, and when I do these steps and when I go to my website(localhost) I see that the new menu item ABOUT US is there and when I clock on it it takes me to about us page but nothing is there,  However if I change the template style to something else like fruitshop style then I can see the about us page with the fuit style and also my about us content but when nor for the original style that I am using.

can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have put your content in sections / modules that your new template might not have defined. [Declaring module positions](https://docs.joomla.org/Declaring_module_positions)

Comment: I am not sure what should i do, can you maybe explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Your new template may have trouble showing the article view, as you state with other templates this don't happen. If this only happens with this particular article maybe you have a plugin that is overwriting template code. If it is not the case change the referrer alias of this page to another value, this can be found on the article properties. Edit your question if still have trouble